# Door Jamb and Moulding as Load Bearing?

Tags: doors, load-bearing, jamb

Recently I've been working on replacing the moulding around the doors in my home, but I've come across a bit of an oddity with the jamb - It's the same piece of wood as the moulding.

I thought it was odd that it didn't look like the moulding was separate when looking at the inside of the frame, but assumed it was probably just layers upon layers of paint.

So I started by scoring the caulking around the edge of the door moulding and then got a putty knife in. But I still couldn't find any indication of a seam inside. I ended up forcing it. splitting the wood at the bottom and sawing a piece off.

It looks like the jamb and the moulding are one piece and the other side has two grooves in it for the drywall to fit in - so it's kind of in the shape of an E. The diagram below is what I imagine it looks like based on what I can see without pulling it out of the wall. The drywall has shifted out of the slot (but I can't get a good picture of it) so I know that the center part doesn't extend into the wall any further.

[image]

I've never seen this before, no one I know has seen this in a ranch style home before, and I can't find anything on the internet about single piece door frames. Now I'm getting a little worried that I shouldn't be pulling the jamb out or that it might be load-bearing.

Wondering if anyone out there has seen this before and might be able to help figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

It’s not structural. It’s just a design we use for “clean lines” without the grooves and notches in the trim, etc.

If you were to remove the entire frame, you’d see that there are shims along the head and jambs. Any structural load can’t be transferred to the jambs if there’s shims in the head, AND the frame can’t be “squared” without the shims.

This design makes the frame look more like hollow metal frames...